# Crash when trying to open MIUI system Activity in Android 13

Tags: intentfilter, xiaomi, miui, android-tiramisu

i am trying to call MIUI system activity by this code:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setClassName("com.miui.powerkeeper", "com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity")
intent.putExtra("package_name", activity.packageName)
intent.putExtra("package_label", getText(R.string.app_name))
startActivity(intent)
```

Before Android 13 everything works fine, but **on Android 13** I catch an error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.miui.powerkeeper/com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
```

Tried to add default intent-filter, but it never helps:

```
<activity android:name="com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="foo" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How to define external intent-filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I determined the presence of the MIUI firmware like this:

```
fun isMIUI() = !TextUtils.isEmpty(AndroidUtilities.getSystemProperty("ro.miui.ui.version.name"))
```

But the bug was reproduced on the magnificent Redmi A2+, which has the firmware Android 13 (Go).

These firmwares do not have proprietary MIUI applications installed and that's why I couldn't run them.

As a result, to solve the problem, you need to change the firmware identification to this:

```
fun isMIUI(context: Context): Boolean {
    val intentList = listOf(
        Intent("miui.intent.action.OP_AUTO_START").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT),
        Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
        Intent("miui.intent.action.POWER_HIDE_MODE_APP_LIST").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT),
        Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.powercenter.PowerSettings"))
    )
    intentList.forEach { intent ->
        val resolved = Internal.resolveActivityList(context, intent).isNotEmpty()
        if (resolved) return true
    }
    return false
}
```

And resolve method:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun resolveActivityList(context: Context, intent: Intent): List<ResolveInfo> = with(context.packageManager) {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong()))
    } else queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
}
```